# How to customize the sharepoint discussion board

Tags: shared-service-provider

i have created a new discussion board in which in my discussion board i have added a new fields named "status". when a new item is created the status will be open and i add new items . when i reply for the new items its get added as new id this is because of two content type one for discussion another(message) for reply. but i could want to know how the body fields in the reply contain the old contents which was posted in the above post.

Regards,
Zakeer Ahamed.S

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint! We need clarification on your question. Are you asking how discussions work? What are you trying to achieve? See [How do I ask questions here?](http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/faq#howtoask) for general guidelines.